# Unable to Import Efficientnet in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, efficientnet

I am working in colab to test a code. While importing models, its giving error No module named 'efficientnet'
I am sharing the code and error here.

```
# for accessing tabular data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
os.chdir('/content/drive/My Drive/')
# adding classweight
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
# Evaluation Metric
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_score, recall_score
# for visualization
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 
from prettytable import PrettyTable
# backend
import keras
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.callbacks import Callback
# for transfer learning
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16, VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.applications import DenseNet121
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50, ResNet152
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
from efficientnet.keras import EfficientNetB0, EfficientNetB3, EfficientNetB4
from keras.applications import Xception
# for model architecture
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, Flatten
# for Tensorboard visualization
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard 
# for Data Augmentation
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxYHt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0, EfficientNetB3, EfficientNetB4
```